# Admob TestAds dont't show up on device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-mobile-ads

Admob's Test ads wont show on any of my test Devices but log that they are loaded in the Unity Editor.

I have resolved the android dependencies and I will show my Manifest and AddCaller and I have the Google Repository and The play services SDK I don't get any errors it just wont show the test ads!

Android MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads. android:minSdkVersion="14"
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">

  <!-- Required -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>
  <!-- Your AdMob App ID will look similar to this sample ID:
    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxx"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

AdScript:

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AddScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string AppID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx";

    private BannerView bannerAD;
    public InterstitialAd interAD;

    public int addTick;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string appId = AppID;

        //Initialize Ads SDK
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
        RequestInterstitial();
        RequestBanner();
    }

    private void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (level == 2)
        {
            ShowInterstitial();
        }

        if(level == 1)
       {
            bannerAD.Show();
       }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.interAD = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxx").Build();

        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        interAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        interAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;

        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.interAD.LoadAd(request);
    }

    private void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (this.interAD.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interAD.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("Interstitial is not ready yet");
        }
    }


    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        bannerAD = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxx").Build();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerAD.LoadAd(request);

    }

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
    RequestInterstitial();
    }
}
```

I expect a test banner to show and an test interstitial but nothing happens.

and there is no error or warning in the console it says the dummy loaded and displayed correctly.

Comment: Try the app using a VPN.

Comment: I have waited multiple days and still nothing and my account has already been approved by admob.

Answer (score 1):

a month ago I generated my first application to publish on android and I used Admob and I had no errors, I assumed that everything was correct, after searching the internet I did not find a solution, the ads were not shown, after 2 days the announcement appeared without changing anything, nowadays I have 3 applications, this happens every time I generate a new application, wait a few days.

Comment: Even for test ads?